# Expected dynamic type string', but had typeint64 react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this line in my react native app to stock a variable in AsyncStorage:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('userId',theuser.id);
```

but when I run the app it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: expected dynamic type string', but had typeint64 react native
```

It works fine when the variable I want to pass is string but I can't pass any object or int variable?

Comment: Is the `id` a number? It has to be a string.

Comment: @AndrewLi it has nothing to do with the type of the id I want pass the age for example but It won't It accepts only string

Comment: What do you mean it has nothing to do with type? The problem is the type -- the value *must be a string*.

Comment: @AndrewLi it has nothing to do with the type of the ID, 
even this "AsyncStorage.setItem('number',15);" will get the same error.

Comment: It has all to do with the type! In your counterexample, the second argument is still a number! It can't be a number! That's what the error is saying!

Comment: @AndrewLi what you said in the first response is about the type OF THE ID in particular, when the problem is about the type of any variable I want to pass.

Comment: Have you tried `AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', String(theuser.id))`? The documentation states that `setItem` takes arguments of type `string, string, [func]`

Comment: @AndrewLi It works, but the thing is I want to be able to pass a whole Object with this, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments above you said you would want to pass a whole object, you would do it like this:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', JSON.stringify(theuser));
```

Comment: but then it gives me this error ( JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF ) when I try to use the field userId.id or userId.department in the app.

Comment: How are you parsing it? Here's an example of what to do: `AsyncStorage.getItem('userId', (err, user) => this.setState({ user: JSON.parse(user) }));`